# Extending monads along dense functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, kan-extension

Let $j: \mathsf A \to \mathsf B$ be a fully faithful and dense functor where $\mathsf A$ is a small category and $\mathsf B$ is cocomplete. Let $(T, \eta, \mu)$ be a monad over $\mathsf A$.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathsf A @>T>> \mathsf A\\
    @V j V V @VV j V\\
    \mathsf B @>>\text{lan}_j(jT)> \mathsf B
\end{CD}

> Is it possible to equip $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ with a monad structure?

**Prop. 1** When $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ preserve itself, the answer is yes. Moreover, if the monad $T$ is idempotent, so is $\text{lan}_j(jT)$.

Sketch of Proof. The map $\text{lan}_j(j \circ \_): \text{End}(\mathsf A) \to \text{End}(\mathsf B)$  is strong monoidal on the full subcategory spanned by the monad $T$ and $1_{\mathsf A}$. Indeed $\text{lan}_j(jT^2) \cong \text{lan}_j(jT)^2,$ because $$\text{lan}_j(jT^2) \cong  \text{lan}_j(\text{lan}_j(jT)jT) \cong \text{lan}_j(jT) \circ \text{lan}_j(jT) = \text{lan}_j(jT)^2. $$

(Observe that part of the functoriality is due to the fact that $j$ is dense). In particular, it maps monoid object to monoid objects.

**Cor. 2** When $j$ is the Yoneda embedding, $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ admits a monad structure.

Proof. By the universal property of the presheaf construction, $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ is cocontinous, thus preserve every (pointwise) Kan extension, in particular, itself.

**Cor. 3** Given a locally $\lambda$-presentable category $\mathsf{A}$ and a  $\lambda$-colimit preserving monad $T: \mathsf{A}_{\lambda} \to \mathsf{A}_{\lambda}$ (the full subcategory of $\lambda$-presentable objects), then there exists an extension $\mathsf{T}: \mathsf{A} \to \mathsf{A}$ admitting a monad structure. Moreover, $\mathsf{T}$ is cocontinuous.

Proof. Similar to **Cor. 2**.

**Cor. 4** When $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ is absolute, $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ admits a monad structure.

> 1. Is the argument in Prop. 1 correct?
> 2. How natural is the hypothesis that $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ preserve itself?
> 3. Are there natural or known assumption under which it is possible to equip $\text{lan}_j(jT)$ with a monad structure?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer to your questions, but one that I imagine recovers all the cases of interest (in particular it gives a conceptual reason why your examples hold when $j$ is the Yoneda embedding and when $j$ is the inclusion $A_\lambda \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Ind}(A_\lambda)$). Suppose that $j$ is *well-behaved* in the sense of [Altenkirch–Chaptman–Uustalu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7148): i.e. $j : A \to B$ admits left Kan extensions along functors $A \to B$, and is fully faithful, dense, and the [nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve) $N_j$ preserves left Kan extensions along $j$. (Such left Kan extensions will always be admitted when $A$ is small and $B$ is cocomplete.) Then $j$ is the inclusion of $A$ under some class $\Phi$ of weighted colimits (Theorem 8.11 of Szlachányi's [On the tensor product of modules over skew monoidal actegories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01353)), and conversely.

In this case, there is a lax idempotent 2-monad $(\mathbf T, \mu, \eta)$ on $\mathbf{CAT}$ for which $\eta_A$ coincides with $j$ (up to equivalence): this follows from Lack–Kelly's [On the monadicity of categories with chosen colimits](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/7/n7/7-07abs.html). By general properties of lax idempotent 2-monads, the action of the 2-functor $\mathbf T$ on functors $f \colon A \to B$ is given by $\mathrm{Lan}_{\eta_A} (\eta_B \circ f)$. Consequently, since 2-monads preserve monads, if $T : A \to A$ has the structure of a monad on $A$, then $\mathbf T(T) \colon \mathbf T(A) \to \mathbf T(A)$ has the structure of a $\Phi$-cocontinuous monad on $\mathbf T(A)$.

You recover your examples for $j$ the Yoneda embedding taking the class of all small weights, and for $j$ the inclusion $A_\lambda \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Ind}(A_\lambda)$ taking the class of filtered weights. All of this works just as well in the enriched setting.